# Using My Own UnqID in List and Library

Tags: workflow

I created the following flow. It almost gets me what I want.

It updates the FMSSID that I want to the new document posted to the Library.

However, the flow is updating the document FMSSID based on the 'ID' created by SharePoint.

My desires is to have my own 'UnqID' used to tie a List Item to a Library Document. I've already created the auto-generating field in PowerApps. The UnqID is uploaded to the List anytime a new document is created. I need that same 'UnqID' referenced in the Patch or Flow so that is also populates along side the new document posted in the Library and acts as its UnqID.

[image]

Comment: How is the document created in the Document Library? [Update file properties] will always need the Document ID (system generated) to update meta data properties of the document. In Flow, when you create a document, it returns the system generated ID, which you could use to update any other meta data of the document from within the same Flow.

Comment: Take a look at the [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QaiM8SeWfM&t=948s) showing how files/attachments can be uploaded to SPO from PowerApss.

Comment: Yes, I've watched that particular video several times. Everything he is doing I have done. I  am able to upload and recall the document I uploaded. My issue is I inherited hundreds of files that also need to be recalled that were no added through a flow, so there is no 'relationship'. I've added a CQUnqID column for the existing files in the Library; which I use as the ID to retrieve to PowerApps. I need that same number (which I now automatically created in PowerApps) Patched/Uploaded with new document uploads.

Comment: I need a condition in a PowerApps button OnSelect that does a Patch of the data to the List (including the 'CQUnqID') and intiates a Flow that uploads the associated document to the Library. All of this I can already do; once this is complete I need a second Flow to trigger on when an Item is Created in the Library (or a Patch statement) that then sends the newly created 'CQUnqID' in the List to the matching column and newly added document in the Library.

Comment: So, you are passing the content of the file from PowerApps to a Flow to create a file in the document library, right? Can you pass 'CQUnqID' from PowerApps to the same Flow?

Comment: That's what I trying to do. The only option I get is 'ID' I have a When an item is created: Library; Get files (properties only): List (no ODATA chosen); Apply to each: Value; Update file properties: Library - 'ID', 'CQUnqID'..... all of that gets me the result I desire but only if the matching 'ID' is in the Library. I've pre-loaded 1300 files, the 'ID's won't match. I've also tied the 'CQUnqID' to the existing data in the List and exact document in the Library. I just need to complete that with all NEW uploads.

Comment: Is your goal is to: Update the uploaded File's meta data, that is, [CQUnqID] with the value from List Item created from PowerApps? You need to post the Flow of your "Upload" file process. **[Create file]** returns the ID and you need to use that ID to update the document meta data. Otherwise, you need another column to match list item with the document.

Comment: Please take a look into [this post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-new-File-in-Sharepoint-and-update-it-s-properties/td-p/61329) shoiwng how files can be created and properties be updated from the within the same flow. You might not need a separate flow using triggers such as 'When a item created..' to accomplish this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124035/discussion-between-curtis-e-troutt-and-matiur-rahman).